# Method to transfer encrypted file

Tags: file, transfer

I have the need to allow persons outwith my organisation to access a limit number of files.

The content of the files can be very varied and can even be source code.

However, the recipients of these files are nearly always non technical, indeed most are barely computer literate.

The majority don't have access to install applications on their desktop.

The majority have significant problems unzipping files, passworded zips cause them to overload.

Executable files (e.g. self extracting) are not an option, the email systems will block the files.

I need a method to send encrypted files.

I am looking for suggestions - I'm assuming it would have to be web based.

Comment: When you say encrypted, does it encrypted in transport or encrypted by the time it reaches the person? If encrypted in transport, you pretty much just use SSL during the transfer

Comment: Something like Dropbox. It is not encrypted per se (only in transport), but that is probably what you want (since people having troubles unzipping files will probably have trouble with decrypting files as well).

Comment: A good question. I suppose if we can confirm who the person is before they view, maybe SSL is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send any file you want over https. It is encrypted enough for everyone, and transparent enough for everyone.

Bear in mind that if your recipients are to get decrypted files on their computers, they can be lost, stolen and emailed to every single contact in their address books. It does not matter how strongly your channel is encrypted.